# How do I get more informative Python syntax errors

Tags: python

I am teaching someone Python. This person executed below

```
if 2 == 2
    print 'hi'
```

which gave

```
    if 2 == 2
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to get Python to say `missing : at end of if statement`?

Comment: If Python could infer what exactly the error is and always suggest the correct solution, it wouldn't need to be a syntax error to begin with; Python could just correct the problem itself. – That is to say, it could take a **best guess** as to what the problem is and suggest it, but this won't be correct every time and may therefore actually detract from the actual solution.

Comment: @shivsn I know. I did write "Is there a way to get Python to say missing : at end of if statement?"

Comment: @deceze for very simple errors like this one it'll be doable I'd think

Comment: When I use code editors, most simple errors would be fixed as I would immediately see a big colour change when a quote is not ended or a parenthesis is not closed. For if statements: When I start a newline, if there is not indent for me, I missed a colon.

Comment: Well, yes, in this specific case a default suggestion like *"invalid syntax, probably missing : at end of statement"* would probably cover many newb cases. But in practice is could be missing `()` or `\ ` in a multi-line statement, an accidental line break between two conditions or many other things...

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get that kind of helpful detail in error messages is to use (or write your own) interpreter/compiler that does so.

Figuring out the exact cause of a syntax error is difficult, and an interpreter or compiler that can usually do so is difficult to write and has a much larger footprint in both memory and in compile/interpret/run time.

When I was in college I learned PL/C, which is a compatible variant of PL/I that does what you want. In fact, it attempted to correct the syntax error and keep compiling the program. Run-time errors were also corrected, as much as possible. The philosophy was to give the programmer as much debug information as possible on each compile or run. That language was only used for development: once a program is debugged, PL/I compiles and runs the program much more quickly. I have never seen the equivalent for Python, but I see no theoretical reason why it could not be done. That seems to be a good topic for PhD dissertation!